# Unknown error while importing .dva file in Oracle Analytics Server 5.5.0

Tags: oracle, oracle-bi, oas, oracle-analytics

I have a problem while I'm trying to import a .dva file generated from Oracle Analytics Desktop into Oracle Analytics Server. It speems that it doesn't come from any specific dva file, it happens with all the files I try to import. For example, the very example dva file that comes with the installation of Oracle Analytics Desktop, "Sample Sales", has the same problem.

After trying to import in OAS Analytics 5.5.0, the following error message appears "Se ha producido un error y no hemos podido importar su archivo .dva. Compruebe los logs para obtener más información", which means that they couldn't import it and suggests to have a look at the logs. In the logs, all I can find is about "Storage Plugin commitImport failed" and raising a java runtime error. I honestly don't know what is the problem and how could I resolve it.

Content of the log after raising the error can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AJhNSJKUW2ijxU7Thf68lwwsTce60ZlS/view?usp=sharing).

Sorry if there is any convention or rule I did not follow; this is the very first question I ask.

Thanks in advance!